# Функция возвращает неверные данные

Tags: php, время, unixtimestamp

Здравствуйте!

есть переменная `$action['date']` в ней хранится unix метка 1524168000 (2018-04-19 20:00:00)

Есть функция:

```
function unixConvert($date) {
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    return $date;
}
```

которая возвращает дату в читабельном виде.

К примеру:

```
echo unixConvert($action['date'])
```

функция должна вернуть вот такую строку 2018-04-19 20:00:00 а возвращает 2018-04-19 23:00:00, то есть на 3 часа больше.

Подскажите в чем может быть дело?

Comment: В time zone вестимо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда в Гринвиче `2018-04-19 20:00:00`, то во временной зоне +3, соответственно `2018-04-19 23:00:00`.

Unix timestamp считается по UTC (зона +0).

Т.е., когда вы передаете в `date` временную метку Unix, то функция считает, что это время по Гринвичу, а текстовое представление возвращает с учетом временной зоны сервера.

Попробуйте выполнить `date("r", $timestamp)` и увидите, какая выставлена зона.

Comment: можно ли по умолчанию установить +3?

Comment: @verstala в качестве грязного хака можете просто добавить к временной метке 3 часа. Либо посмотрите функцию http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Answer (score 0):

В качестве самого простого (и не самого оптимального решения) можно  расширить вашу функцию, чтобы принимала разницу в часах и учитывала ее:

```
function unixConvert($date, $timezone) {
    $timeshift = $timezone * 3600;
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date + $timeshift);
    return $date;
}
```